# Plotly - change order of subplots

Tags: python, plotly

I would like to change the order of the subplots, e.g. by sorting by the mean, starting with the lowest.
Currently: Blue, Red, Green.
Desired: Red, Green, Blue

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1, subplot_titles=('Blue', 'Red', 'Green'))
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[3, 4, 5],
    y=[1000, 1100, 1200],
), row=1, col=1)

fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[2, 3, 4],
    y=[10, 11, 12]
), row=2, col=1)

fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2],
    y=[100, 110, 120],
), row=3, col=1)


fig.update_layout(height=600, width=600, title_text="Stacked Subplots")
fig.show()
```

Comment: Change the subplot titles list to correspond to the desired order, then change the `row=` parameter of each plot to position the graphs accordingly.  If you haven’t already, I recommend reviewing the plotly docs.  This is very clearly / intuitively explained.

Comment: Thank you, I am not very experienced. Your hint made things much clearer for me!

Downvote is infortunate. I had checked
https://plotly.com/python/subplots/
and did not find what I was looking for.

Live n learn :)

Comment: I already upvoted your initial post.
If you post a proper answer, I will upvote it as well. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the order of the subplots, simply:

- Update the `subplot_titles` parameter to order the titles
- Update the `row=` parameter of each plot to position the graph accordingly

Here's a link to that section of the [Plotly docs](https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/#adding-traces-to-subplots).  Albeit, says basically the same thing as the subplot docs you've reviewed.